# How can I restrict YouTube videos that can't be played in the US, on iOS?

Tags: ios

How can I restrict YouTube videos that can't be played in the US?

```
- (void)loadMediaListWithQuery:(NSString *)query
                        offset:(int)offset
                     withBlock:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *mediaArray, NSError *error))block
{
    NSError *searchError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"No video Found!" code:120 userInfo:NULL];
    query = [query isEqualToString:@""] == TRUE ? defaultSearchQuery : query;

    NSString *searh_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?q=%@&orderby=relevance&start-index=%d&max-results=20&v=2&time=all_time&alt=json",youtubeSearhURL,query,offset];

    NSURLRequest *urlReques = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Utils convertSpaceString:searh_url]]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                         initWithRequest:urlReques];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation
                                               , id responseObject)
     {
         NSError *error=NULL;
         NSMutableArray *mediaArray = [NSMutableArray array];

         NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                                 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error:&error];

         NSMutableArray *tempDic=[[jsonDic valueForKey:@"feed"] objectForKey:@"entry"];
         for (int i=0;i < tempDic.count;i++) {
             @autoreleasepool {
                 MediaEntity *post = [[MediaEntity alloc] initDataWithDic:[tempDic objectAtIndex:i]];
                 [mediaArray addObject:post];
             }
         }
         if (block) {
             tempDic.count > 0 ? block(mediaArray,NULL) : block(NULL,searchError);
         }
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         if (block) {
             block(NULL,error);
         }
     }
     ];
    [operation start];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LBYouTubeView has been discontinued. I won't fix any issues anymore. Although this approach fixes a couple of issues, it does not work reliably enough. Check out XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController. It's similar to this project but seems to work better as its way of extracting the video URL is less jacky.

**Use Link**: https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView